# Can't display JSON-objects from session-storage in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, json, angularjs-scope

I'm having problem displaying a JSON-object named "currentSet" from session-storage. When I instead use a JSON-file from a folder everything works fine, which means the HTML-code is probably fine. I have narrowed the problem down to either the $scope.set or the loadQuiz-function and have tried several things, but can't get it to work. This is the relevant parts from the controller:

```
    $scope.set = angular.fromJson(sessionStorage.getItem('currentSet')); //doesn't work
    //$scope.set = 'data/konflikter.js'; //works

    $scope.defaultConfig = {
        'autoMove': true,
        'pageSize': 1,
        'showPager': false
    }

    $scope.onSelect = function (question, choice) {
          question.choices.forEach(function (element, index, array) {
            question.Answered = choice;
          });

        if ($scope.defaultConfig.autoMove == true && $scope.currentPage < $scope.totalItems) {
            $scope.currentPage++;
        }
        else {
            $scope.onSubmit();
        }
    }

    $scope.onSubmit = function () {
        var answers = [];
        $scope.questions.forEach(function (question, index) {
            answers.push({'questionid': question._id, 'answer': question.Answered});
        });
        $http.post('https://fhsclassroom.mybluemix.net/api/quiz/submit', answers).success(function (data, status) {
            $location.path('/');
        });
    }

    $scope.pageCount = function () {
        return Math.ceil($scope.questions.length / $scope.itemsPerPage);
    };

    $scope.loadQuiz = function (data) {
        $http.get(data)
         .then(function (res) {
             $scope.name = res.data.name;
             $scope.questions = res.data.questions;
             $scope.totalItems = $scope.questions.length;
             $scope.itemsPerPage = $scope.defaultConfig.pageSize;
             $scope.currentPage = 1;

             $scope.$watch('currentPage + itemsPerPage', function () {
                 var begin = (($scope.currentPage - 1) * $scope.itemsPerPage),
                   end = begin + $scope.itemsPerPage;

                 $scope.filteredQuestions = $scope.questions.slice(begin, end);
             });
         });
    }
    $scope.loadQuiz($scope.set);
```

Comment: can you check how your session storage looks like by just typing in console: sessionStorage

Comment: @pegla Yes, I have checked with firebug, my session-storage contains the data I want, which is the same as the data in the 'data/konflikter.js'-file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I figured out what's wrong, you are loading file so you need to get file - or import it to get the contents that's why it works with your:

```
$scope.set = 'data/konflikter.js'; //works but combined with http request
```

If you wish to pass data from dataStorage you will need to change your loadQuiz not to have http request like this:

```
$scope.loadQuiz = function (res) {
    $scope.name = res.data.name;
    $scope.questions = res.data.questions;
    $scope.totalItems = $scope.questions.length;
    $scope.itemsPerPage = $scope.defaultConfig.pageSize;
    $scope.currentPage = 1;

    $scope.$watch('currentPage + itemsPerPage', function () {
        var begin = (($scope.currentPage - 1) * $scope.itemsPerPage),
            end = begin + $scope.itemsPerPage;

        $scope.filteredQuestions = $scope.questions.slice(begin, end);
    });
}
```

Comment: No problem, let me know if it works, and you can also accept answer and vote it up if it helped, same you can do with all your previous answers, that way you will probably get more people to help you and earn few badges here as well.

Comment: It didn't quite work, although you were on the right track. I solved it like I show in the answer. Thank you for the guidance!

Answer (score 0):

With the help of @pegla I was able to solve the problem like this:

```
$scope.loadQuiz = function () { 

        $scope.set = angular.fromJson(sessionStorage.getItem('currentSet'));

        $scope.questionsetid = $scope.set.questions[0].questionsetid;
        $scope.name = $scope.set.name;
        $scope.questions = $scope.set.questions;
        $scope.totalItems = $scope.set.questions.length;
        $scope.itemsPerPage = $scope.defaultConfig.pageSize;
        $scope.currentPage = 1;

        $scope.$watch('currentPage + itemsPerPage', function () {
             var begin = (($scope.currentPage - 1) * $scope.itemsPerPage),
               end = begin + $scope.itemsPerPage;

             $scope.filteredQuestions = $scope.questions.slice(begin, end);
        });
    }

    $scope.loadQuiz();
```